# Unexpected behavior of displaying and hiding a popup menu after resizing a screen or changing screen orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I'm working on a menu which allows me to open and close pop up content. The menu can be opened by pressing a button, and closed by clicking button once more or clicking anywhere else other than pop-up content container.

When I'm using my code, I am experiencing a weird issue where after resizing a window or changing screen orientation for example on tablet, and then clicking menu button, the pop-up won't stay opened. It opens and hides itself right after opening.

I cannot duplicate this error in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YsgK/) but I made an example where I am using the same code.

Why am I experiencing this issue on my demo page? How to avoid it? Does my code have some sort of limitations I'm not aware of?

This is a function that is trowed on click handler on each of the buttons.

```
function mainMenuFunction(eid) {
    var num = $(eid).attr('id').substr($(eid).attr('id').length - 1);
    var elem = $("#menu-content-" + num);
    var parent = $("#menu-item-" + num);
    var p = parent.position();
    var o = parent.offset();

    if (elem.css("display") == "none") {
        elem.slideDown();
    } else {
        elem.slideUp();
    }

    $(document).click(function (e) {
        // position of the menu item
        var hstart = o.left;
        var hend = o.left + parent.width();
        var vstart = o.top;
        var vend = o.top + parent.height();

        // position of the menu container
        var chstart = elem.offset().left;
        var chend = elem.offset().left + elem.width();
        var cvstart = elem.offset().top;
        var cvend = elem.offset().top + elem.height();

        if (!(((e.clientX >= hstart) && (e.clientX <= hend)) && ((e.clientY >= vstart) && (e.clientY <= vend)))) {
            if (!(((e.clientX >= chstart) && (e.clientX <= chend)) && ((e.clientY >= cvstart) && (e.clientY <= cvend)))) {
                elem.slideUp();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

On jsFiddle this code is there to close all menus when user resizes page. So my mobile and pc menu doesn't mess up while switching screens. The issue isn't that the menu closes when resizing a window and hiding menu content, but that after resizing the window, then clicking the menu causes to open and then closing the menu content. The content isn't staying open.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    // PC main menu items
    $("#menu-content-1").hide();
    $("#menu-content-2").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I have encountered was caused by the Animation sequence. The animation took too long to perform and didn't allow the entire script to execute, therefore some event handlers wasn't able to be activated on time. The solution for this problem was to remove completely or really speed up the animations of the element hiding or displaying.

Answer (score 0):

What Is the Purpose Of that script. explain please

```
  if (!(((e.clientX >= hstart) && (e.clientX <= hend)) && ((e.clientY >= vstart) && (e.clientY <= vend)))) {
            if (!(((e.clientX >= chstart) && (e.clientX <= chend)) && ((e.clientY >= cvstart) && (e.clientY <= cvend)))) {
                elem.slideUp();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm using this so if user resizes window it hides all menu elements, this way my mobile menu and main pager menu doesn't get messed up. I mean, the problem isn't that the menu hides when resizing a window, but after resizing, then clicking on menu the menu container opens and closes right away.

Comment: @HelpNeeder let me check

Comment: have you changed anything?

Comment: no, even i compared old code and new code, they are identical, nut now its working.

Comment: This looks for coordinates of menu button, and menu content container. If mouse click is located outside of them (while menu container is open), it will cause the menu content container to collapse. This is so when user click on second menu item or anywhere else, the menu content container will automatically close.